# number keys above keyboard not work, only 5 and 6

Tags: keyboard

I am running Ubuntu 14.04, and suddenly my number keys above the keyboard stopped working, as well as all the symbol keys above them (for instance, the exclamation mark !, parentheses, etc.).  The only keys in this row that work are the 5 and 6, and the keys on the far ends, before the 1 and after the 0.  This really renders the computer practically unusable.  The Numpad works fine when numlock is turned on. I have numbers in my password, so I have to use the numpad even to log in to my computer.  Is there something I can do?  I have searched through ask ubuntu, and google, and nothing really matches.  Is this a hardware problem, just replace the keyboard, or is there a setting somewhere that got changed?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you try another keyboard already to eliminate keyboard failure? That would be my first try. I don't know any stetting that would do that.

Comment: I did test it with another keyboard, and that was indeed the solution.  Intuitively, I did not at first suspect it was a hardware problem, because it just stopped working.  And just those 8 keys and no others...  But so it was, and now I can work again.  Thanks for the help!  Would you like to post the answer?

Comment: Nah, Just glad I could be of assistance. Your welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I borrowed a keyboard and found that it was indeed a hardware problem.  I have replaced the keyboard, and can type again!